# After Updating Excel PivotTable DataSource w/ VBA, ERROR: The PivotTable report was saved without the underlying data

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I've been working on a macro that copies a series of pivot tables on multiple tabs along with the data source tab to a new workbook.  When copying the pivot tables over to the new workbook, they were hanging on to the data source from the original workbook.

To overcome this issue I added the following code to my macro.

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim ws as Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
         pt.ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
           (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Worksheets("Raw").Range("A3:AP125000"))
Next pt
Next ws

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

This seemed to solve the problem and everything worked fine, until I added further code to save each of the resulting files.  The files saved fine, but after you opened and tried to filter or change a pivot table, you got the following message, "The PivotTable report was saved without the underlying data. Use the Refresh Data command to update the report".  If you refresh the individual pivot table or click Refresh All in Excel, the issue is fixed and all is well... For now...  You can save the file again, but next time you open it, the same issue happens..  I don't want to create that burden for the users that will be opening these files...

Wondering why the ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll in my macro is not working/sticking, and opening up the file and clicking Refresh All in Excel fixes the problem for a single session only?  Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Here is my code in its entirety:

```
Sub CreateFiles()


With Application
.Calculation = xlAutomatic
.ScreenUpdating = False
.DisplayAlerts = False
End With


'Paste Values on Raw data tab
Sheets("Raw").Select
Range("A3:M125000").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

'Create a new workbook for each facility in column A on the Macro tab, also stamp the facility ID on 
the Raw data tab
Worksheets("Macro").Activate
Dim bottomA As Integer
bottomA = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim c As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each c In Range("A2:A" & bottomA)
    Set ws = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = Worksheets(c.Value)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        Sheets("Raw").Select
        With ActiveSheet
        .Range("B2").Value = c.Value
    End With
    End If


'Copy only the tabs you need
Sheets(Array("Referral - Origin", "Admission - Origin", "Denial - Origin", _
    "Referral - Physician", "Admission - Physician", "Denial - Physician", _
    "Referral - Referral Source", "Admission - Referral Source", _
    "Denial - Referral Source", "Raw")).Copy




'Now we can paste values on the Raw data tab for the remaing cells we were waiting on, dependent on 
the facility ID stamp
Sheets("Raw").Select
Range("A1:AP3").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Sheets("Raw").Select
Range("N4:N125000").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False



'Delete extra rows on the Raw data tab to minimize file space
Worksheets("Raw").Activate
Range("N4:N125000").Replace "False", "#N/A", xlWhole
On Error Resume Next
Range("N4:N125000").SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete
On Error GoTo 0


'Hide raw tab
Sheets("Raw").Visible = False


'Fix PivotTable DataSource so that it points to newly created workbook rather than the original 
workbook
Dim pt As PivotTable


For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
         pt.ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
            (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Worksheets("Raw").Range("A3:AP125000"))
Next pt
Next ws


'Go to first tab and pivots refresh

Sheets("Referral - Origin").Select
Range("A1").Select

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

'Save workbook

ChDir "C:\Temp"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Temp\" & Worksheets("Raw").Range("B2") & "_" & 
Worksheets("Raw").Range("C2") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:= _
xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

'Close newly created workbook

 ActiveWorkbook.Close



'Repeat

Next c


 With Application
.DisplayAlerts = True
.ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I ended up ditching the idea of trying to copy copy certain sheets to a new workbook and edit the pivot source data..   Instead, I just used a macro to edit and create multiple copies of the original workbook.  Much easier and works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

I know you found a work around for this, but I had this same problem and I found that setting the SaveData property of the pivot table to "true" gets rid of the error.
I didnt test this, but for example your code could be :

```
For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
     pt.ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
        (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Worksheets("Raw").Range("A3:AP125000"))
     pt.SaveData = True
Next pt
```